# C# XNA - Drawing into a form that is bigger than the main window

Tags: xna

Drawing into a form that is bigger than the main window with GraphicsDevice.Present results in the form cutting the stuff that is drawn along an imaginary border, which has exactly the size of the main window. I added a picture to be clear

[image: img]

The red rectangle has the same size as the Main Form.
Main Form is an XNA Game, whereas Secondary Form is a Windows Form, which Main Form draws on with GraphicsDevice.Present

I tried setting the Viewport which results in an exception.

Comment: Posting some of the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [official WinForms sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1). It has correct support for multiple windows (and includes an explanation of how it works).

The `Game` class doesn't support this.